# Angular 4 and Prerender.io

Tags: angular

I have been trying to incorporate Angular 4 with prerender.io for SEO pages, but I am not able to see the HTML page; it is stuck on the preloader loading the page. I am definitely missing something.

http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com works, and properly redirects to https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=mnT4WdOfEovz8Aedr4ZQ

However, http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:4200 doesn't work: it gets stuck on the loader page.

Is prerender.io compatible with Angular 4? Is this issue specific to Angular 4?

Regards

Sajal

Comment: the links you have provided are from your local machine, we can't run them...please show us some code!

Comment: I have tried to install preloader.io in my local server plus i also have the angular application in my local. For installing preloader.io I followed this https://github.com/prerender/prerender and for angular https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. Then through cmd i ran the two applications separately on different ports  http://localhost:3000 for prerender and /localhost:4200 for angular

Comment: Try the chrome branch of our open source Prerender.io server: https://github.com/prerender/prerender/tree/chrome. The Chrome server should render your pages just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular 2+, you should be using [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) for Server Side Rendering.

If you are using the CLI, you can follow [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering) guide to set it up correctly.

Comment: Hi Ivan I have tried following https://github.com/prerender/prerender/tree/chrome with a very basic Angular 4 appplication but it gets stuck at the loader and the html page is never loaded.

Comment: 2017-11-02T06:28:46.740Z getting http://localhost:4200/
2017-11-02T06:28:46.754Z started phantom
2017-11-02T06:28:46.759Z started phantom
TypeError: pre,template,textarea,script,style is not iterable!

  http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:804 in exports
  http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:341
  http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:1801 in Set
  http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:27948 in ../../../compiler/@angular/com
piler.es5.js   ..  This is what i get in terminal when i hit this url http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:4200  in the browser

Comment: Hi @SajalSunderka , I don't know how prerender works, but I just checked their website and they are advertised as compatible with AngularJS, and they don't mention Angular, so I think it is not compatible.

Comment: @SajalSunderka Also as I said, you should be using Angular Universal. Angular 5 was released yesterday, so I suggest upgrading to v5 and setting up Angular Universal on your project. It's very easy, it's all explained on the link on my answer.

Comment: @IvanAguilar even if angular universal seems easy to set up, for me it didn't work because the libraries(ng-bootstrap) i'm using are not fully compatible with it. So I'm thinking about using prerender.io but I don't know if it's working.

Comment: Hey there @KevinVincent. Libraries that access the DOM are not compatible with Server Side Rendering, so I'm not entirely sure if prerender.io will solve that for you. I was actually developing an app with angular 5 and ng-bootstrap but ended up doing an isomorphic react app.

Comment: @KevinVincent I just checked the prerender.io site and they now say: "prerender.io is compatible with all JavaScript frameworks and libraries".

Comment: @IvanAguilar. There are too many libraries which are not working with universal because of the dom access. I'm about to remove ng-bootstrap and use angular material but this is a hard work. Regarding prerender.io, i saw google deprecated all this kind of methods so I'm not sure if using it is a good idea.